# The Geodynamics of Tidally Locked Planets

Tags: planets, space, solar-system

Would the tidal forces of the star a tidally locked world orbits have any effects on the Geodynamics of the planet?

I imagine that the tidal forces would pull the crust thin at the Terminator making a weak point for magma to flow. Creating volcanos and on worlds with plate tectonics being common place for seafloor spreading and maybe even acting as a barrier for plates moving from one side of the planet to the other because said seafloor spreading.

Answer (score 1):

> Would the tidal forces of the star a tidally locked world orbits have any effects on the Geodynamics of the planet?

Unless disturbed by the gravitational influence of other bodies, the tidal forces on the tidally locked world will be effectively zero.

In our own solar system, you can look at the geology of [Io](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Io_(moon)#Tidal_heating). Tidal forces are induced as a result of Io's eccentric orbit, and the eccentricity is caused by orbital resonances with two of its fellow Jovian moons.

> I imagine that the tidal forces would pull the crust thin at the Terminator making a weak point for magma to flow

Tidal forces aren't strongest at the terminator, but lets not worry about that too much.

Io's volcanoes are, in fact, distributed across the world more than you might expect. It is believed there is a layer of molten magma under the surface that will spread heat around to some extent.

> worlds with plate tectonics

Honestly, its hard to say what would happen there. There's not really a whole lot of tectonic action going on in the solar system, and the place with most of it is not tidally locked or heated.

If your world has a sufficiently runny mantle tectonics could conceivably still occur, but I don't know if a body could be tidally heated enough to that state without becoming an Io-like hellworld, too hot to have any kind of sea. A more Earthlike world with internal heat driven by radioactive decay could behave differently, but you'd have to site it carefully so that the combination of tidal heat and decay heat didn't cause a hellworld, too. That sort of positioning will reduce the influence of tidal heating, so the effects you're thinking of will be less pronounced.